# What are the best ways to give design feedback to mobile app developers?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application, feedback, ux-designer

I'm product designer working remotely with a team of iOS & android app developers on a redesign project of their mobile app. The final designs are done on Adobe XD. The redesigned app looks great however the finer details require some more work and needs to be perfected. I have tried visual feedback tool like trackduck for mobile websites. How do I give my comments visually on the finer details of design to the app development team.

Kindly recommend any tools or process.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is both a duplicate question and also potentially leading to software recommendations, which is more suitable for other communities like Software Recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

**First you need to consult with developers** and find out what works for them.

They'll might just say whatever works for you, or they might have some specific requests, but there's not point in researching a solution on your own only to find that it doesn't suit the workflow.

The simplest method is to **request flattened exports of screens and use any tool that allows for annotation/markup** e.g. Windows Paint, Mac Preview, Snagit, Photoshop.

Managing all the different versions of the files, however, can introduce inefficiencies, which is a problem that **design collaboration tools like [ConceptShare](https://www.conceptshare.com/)** try to solve. Conceptshare allows for the uploading of static images which can commented on by several collaborated and the software allows for the easy version management of the assets.

Answer (score 1):

The most common practice is that designers pop Sketch into Invision where a team can add collaborative notations as well as view how the animations and transitions work. Take a look at that program, as well as Figma which is becoming a favorite pick for handoff, too. Both are collaborative tools that work for teams.

Comment: For this, I would love to pick Zeplin; the designer may export things from Adobe XD, Figma, Sketch, etc. on Zeplin directly. And, the developers then may just write comments/feedbacks and all there, easily.